# Transform data in rows to columnar form

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m, data-transform

I need to do a transformation in PowerBI.

From this,

```
Java    x   x1  x2
OS      y
MS      Z   Z2
```

to this,

```
Java    x
Java    x1
Java    x2
OS      y
MS      Z
MS      Z2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, to show the community your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do **Unpivot other colums** in the Transform menu from edit queries.
Please refer below pic.

[image]